# Retrofit trailing slash on relative urls

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, endpoint, trailing-slash

Does `Retrofit` remove the trailing slash from a relative url for an endpoint?  I have tried adding the trailing slash on one of my endpoints but when i step through with a debugger and i look at the `Call` object, if I drill into the delete.relativeUrl it does not show the trailing slash.

Comment: For those who end up here accidentally here is pretty good answer for question in subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53211672/using-retrofit-to-get-url-from-different-relative-paths

Answer (score 14):

You need to manually add the slash at the end of the base URL endpoint.

Let's say you have this two instances of retrofit:

#### No Slash

```
Retrofit retrofitNoSlash = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/v5")
        .build();
```

- `@GET("something")`: `https://example.com/api/v5something`
- `@GET("/something")`: `https://example.com/something`

#### With Slash

```
Retrofit retrofitWithSlash = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.com/api/v5/")
        .build();
```

- `@GET("something")`: `https://example.com/api/v5/something`
- `@GET("/something")`: `https://example.com/something`

---

so: add the trailing slash manually

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. Just remove slash with base url because back slash already added begin with end point url in GET method.

NetworkInterface.java

```
@GET("/baking.json")
Call<List<ResponseModel>> getRecepies();

public static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(URLs.RECEPIES_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

URLs.java

```
  public static String RECEPIES_URL="https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/5907926b_baking";
```