# Using retrofit to get url from different relative paths

Tags: android, json, dynamic, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to get the CompanyEndpoint for each client's site but I am confused with the use of retrofit on the interface.

Here's what I have so far:

```
CompanyName : "company1"
CompanyEndpoint : "https://example.com"
IdentityEndpoint : "https://example.com/identity"
AppLoginMode : "Anonymous"
```

AppRouterApi.java

```
public interface AppRouterApi {

    @GET("api/sites/{CompanyName}")
    Call<Company> getCompanyName (@Url  String companyName);


}
```

Company.java

```
public class Company {

    String Endpoint;

    public String getEndpoint() {
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://example.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        appRouterApi = retrofit.create(AppRouterApi.class);


        getCompany();


    }

    private void getCompany(){
        retrofit2.Call<Company> companyRequest = appRouterApi.getCompanyName(); //Error here saying a string cant be applied to ()
        companyRequest.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<Company>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<Company> call, retrofit2.Response<Company> response) {

                if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                    textViewResult.setText("Code:" + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                Company company = response.body();
                String content = "";
                content += "Url" + company.getEndpoint();
                textViewResult.setText(content);


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<Company> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

https://example/sites/{companyName}

So if I search for:
https://example/sites/company1

The JSON will have one object and I need to get the endpoint URL value which would be: https://company1.com

Edit: My textViewReslt is returning 403

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit 2 - Dynamic URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on as far as I can tell. Let me break it into chunks.

First thing is you're confusing the annotation `@Path` with the annotation `@Url`. They serve different purposes.

You use `@Path` when you want to format a bit of the path into the url inside the annotations like `@GET`.

```
public interface AppRouterApi {
  @GET("api/sites/{CompanyName}")
  Call<Company> getCompanyName (@Path("CompanyName")  String companyName);
}
```

This interface will format the argument passed to `getCompanyName` as part of the path. Calling `getCompanyName("foo")` will call the endpoint `"https://example.com/api/sites/foo"`.

You use `@Url` when you want to simply call that url. In this case, you only annotate the interface method with the http method. For example,

```
public interface AppRouterApi {
  @GET
  Call<Company> getCompanyName (@Url String url);
}
```

You then would have to call the method with the entire url. To call the same url as before you'd have to call `getCompanyName("https://example.com/api/sites/foo")`.

This is the main difference of usage between these 2 annotations. The reason why you're seeing null in your text view is because you're model's attribute name doesn't match the json. You have 2 options.

First, you can change the model to:

```
public class Company {

   String CompanyEndpoint;

   public String getEndpoint() {
     return endpoint;
   }
}
```

`CompanyEndpoint` is the exact same name as you have in the json. Another approach, is to tell your json serializer what name you want to use. Since you're using `gson`, you can use `@SerializedName` like so:

```
public class Company {

   @SerializedName("CompanyEndpoint")
   String Endpoint;

   public String getEndpoint() {
     return endpoint;
   }
}
```

`@SerializedName("CompanyEndpoint")` tells `gson` which name to use while serializing and deserializing.

In essence, you have 2 options. You either use the endpoint, or the company's name. If you don't expect the domain to change, I'd suggest using the first approach with the `@Path` annotation. This is what it's usually done with Retrofit and personally, I think it's easier to handle than passing urls around. My suggestion is, use a model like:

```
public class Company {

   @SerializedName("CompanyName")
   String name;

   public String getName() {
     return name;
   }
}
```

This would let you access the company's name property and call `getCompanyName(company.getName())`. Retrofit would format the company's name into the path and you'd call the right url.

Comment: Worked perfectly, much appreciated. What if i want to change the relative url on runtime. i.e.  on my app I enter a code for my company, lets say 'comany1' this then goes to 'https://example.com/api/sites/company1' which requests the endpoint url which would be 'https://company1.com'. Repeating my getCompany() method for each . company doesnt seem efficient

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider the approach with `@Url`